# ¿Cómo crear un Fragment desde un Fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un Fragment en el cual he creado un FloatingActionButton y cuando lo pulse quiero que se cree un nuevo Fragment o Activity donde pueda añadir una serie de parametros

```
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(this);
```

esa es la declaracion del FloatingActionButton desde el 
`public View onCreateView`
En el metodo `public void onClick(View v)` he declarado:

`Intent intent = new Intent(new AddClothesActivity(), ClothesFragment.class);
        startActivity(intent);`

ClothesFragment es el Fragment en el que estoy y AddClothesActivity el Activity al que quiero ir, pero no funciona

Comment: El titulo es incorrecto, en realidad deseas ir a la Activity desde un Fragment.

Comment: @Jorgesys efectivamente

Comment: ah pues el intent requiere como contexto la Activity en este caso la que contiene el Fragment, y debes definir la Activity que deseas abrir: Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddClothesActivity.class); agregué respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que deseas es desde el `Fragment` llamado `ClothesFragment` ir a la `Activity` `AddClothesActivity`, en este caso puedes cargar una Activity mediante un Intent usando como contexto la activity que contiene el Fragmente mediante `getActivity()`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddClothesActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```